# Probability Change of variables different to textbook answer

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Problem:
Let $X$ be a random variable with the with density function given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(X) = \begin{cases}
\big( U(-1,1), & \text{for} -1 \le x \le 1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray*}

(a) Find the density function of $Y = X^2$.

$u: x \rightarrow x^2$
$v: y \rightarrow \sqrt{y}$

\begin{eqnarray*}
F_Y( y ) &=& P( v(X^2) \le v(y) ) \\
&=& P( X \le \sqrt{y} ) \\
&=& F_X(\sqrt{y})\\
&=& \int_{-1}^{\sqrt{y}} \frac{1}{2}dx \\
&=& [\frac{x}{2}]_{-1}^{\sqrt{2}} \\
&=& \frac{\sqrt{y}}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Hence:

\begin{eqnarray*}
F_y( y ) &=& \frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y) \\
&=& \frac{d}{dy}(\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2} + \frac{1}{2}) \\
&=& -\frac{1}{4\sqrt{y}}  \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus taking the absolute value:

\begin{eqnarray*}
F_y( y ) &=& \frac{1}{4\sqrt{y}}  \\
\end{eqnarray*}

The answer given is:

\begin{eqnarray*}
F_y( y ) &=& \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}  \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Have I gone wrong?
If so where?

Comment: $P(Y \leq y)$ is not equal to $P(X \leq \sqrt y)$. It is $P(-\sqrt y \leq X \leq \sqrt y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ P(Y<y) =P(\phi(X)<y)\Rightarrow P(X <\phi^{-1}(y))= P(X^2 < y) = P(-\sqrt{y}<X<\sqrt{y}) = \int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}f(x)dx$